# jaxb2-maven-plugin is giving me a SAXParseException when trying to generate META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode file

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, pom.xml, jaxb2

Im getting the following error when trying to generate the episode file using xjc2-maven-plugin. This error seems to be with META-INF folder creation.
Any idea on how to solve this. I have been stuck of this for quite some time.
the command line equivalent xjc command seems to work with the same inputs.

```
[INFO] parsing a schema...
[INFO] compiling a schema...
[ERROR] null[-1,-1]
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; Failed to write to src\main\generated\META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.episode.PluginImpl.run(PluginImpl.java:209)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:294)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:363)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.AbstractXjcMojo.execute(AbstractXjcMojo.java:316)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder
java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\generated\META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode (The system cannot find the path
specified)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.episode.PluginImpl.run(PluginImpl.java:170)
        ... 24 more
```

The snippet of pom.xml

```
    <properties>
    <jaxb.mojo.version>1.6</jaxb.mojo.version>
</properties>
     .
     .
     .

        <plugin>
            <!-- xjc -p com.test.framework.contracts ./main/xsd/Framework.xsd -d ./main/generated -episode ./main/generated/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode -->
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.mojo.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc-framework</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaFiles>Framework.xsd</schemaFiles>
                        <arguments>-episode src/main/generated/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode</arguments>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated</outputDirectory>
                        <packageName>com.test.framework.contracts</packageName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

However changing the line  episode argument

```
<arguments>-episode src/main/generated/sun-jaxb.episode</arguments>
```

makes the compilation pass.
Please help, i need the episode file to be generated by META-INF.

Comment: One things looks wrong: 'Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\generated\META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode (The system cannot find the path
specified)'. So you are generating in the src folder which should be prevented. Generation should be done in target folder instead.

Comment: ideally that should not matter as i use the build-helper-maven-plugin to add src/main/generated to the class path.

Comment: You are not adding to the classpath i assume you are adding it to the source path which results in compiling the sources.